# Xcode 6: 2 Different AVAudioPlayers won't play at same time?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6, avfoundation, avaudioplayer

I'm making an app in which I have 2 different audio players (aplayer and beat). aplayer plays a song selected from the music library and beat adds an extra beat to the mix. The problem is that when I try and play the two together, i.e.:

```
[aplayer play];
[beat play];
```

Whichever one I play first plays and the other stays silent.

Answer (score 1):

The watch comes out in 3 days, I would certainly not expect to be reviewed and available in the store by then. That's not how this process generally works unless you need an update because of some massive issue you introduced in a previous update and convince them to expedite it which, in and of itself, usually isn't allowed to happen.

Anyway - straight from the docs.

> **Playing Multiple Sounds Simultaneously**
>
> To play multiple sounds simultaneously, create one playback audio queue object for each sound. For each audio queue, schedule the first buffer of audio to start at the same time using the AudioQueueEnqueueBufferWithParameters function.
>
> Audio format is critical when you play sounds simultaneously on iPhone or iPod touch. This is because playback of certain compressed formats in iOS employs an efficient hardware codec. Only a single instance of one of the following formats can play on the device at a time:
>
> - AAC
> - ALAC (Apple Lossless)
>   MP3
>
> To play high quality, simultaneous sounds, use linear PCM or IMA4 audio.
>
> The following list describes how iOS supports audio formats for individual or multiple playback:
>
> Linear PCM and IMA/ADPCM (IMA4) audio You can play multiple linear PCM or IMA4 format sounds simultaneously in iOS without incurring CPU resource problems.
>
> AAC, MP3, and Apple Lossless (ALAC) audio Playback for AAC, MP3, and Apple Lossless (ALAC) sounds uses efficient hardware-based decoding on iPhone and iPod touch. You can play only one such sound at a time.

Comment: If your source is the user's music library, I can guarantee that the audio format will not be linear PCM or IMA4. Unless you rethink the source of aplayer's audio and bundle it with the app, you can't play those sounds simultaneously using AVAudioPlayer without conversion. You need to study the docs.